# how to pass a string value in an msgbox vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vbscript

i have a msgbox in vb.net and in else statement.....
i want to pass an string value in it to display the string and the message text like below-

```
Normal

    msgbox("student is not eligible for the company")

TO

    MSGBOX([string]"is not eligible for the company")

RESULT

    Anthony is not eligible for the company
```

any work around on this..........?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dim StudentName as string
StudentName = "Student"

If (specificStudent) Then
   StudentName = "SpecificName"
End If

MsgBox(StudentName + " is not eligible")
```

EDIT: Also, you could use `string.Format` here

```
dim StudentName as string
StudentName = "Student"

If (specificStudent) Then
   StudentName = "SpecificName"
End If

'I suppose string.format works same way in vb.net, as it does in c#    
MsgBox(String.Format("{0} is not eligible", StudentName))
```

Comment: @user1897472: That was added to give an example.